# Probability of getting random coloured side of Rubik's cube twice in a row

Tags: probability

I was solving my Rubik's cube when I though that if i toss my cube what is the probability of getting red colour twice in a row. So I calculate that it is 1/6 for first time, 1/6 possibility for second time getting a red and 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/36 is the answer.

But then I thought if the colour is unspecified i.e the colour that come when i toss my cube one time is taken to be the input colour to come twice in a row.

If i toss my cube then a random colour, it can be red, white etc. come then for the second time it has to be same, would it change the probability.

In short, will the probability of getting a random colour twice on tossing a cube be same a getting as specified colour?

(English is not my native language so it might not make sense)

Comment: The colour you get on the first toss does not matter, it only matters what your second toss is. What is the probability of getting some particular colour, as you need to with your second toss (I see you know how to solve this already)?

Comment: So th probablity will become 1/6 as first toss does not matter?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Rubik's cube is actually solved, so all sides have one color, but different from each other.

Then: the probability of getting a *specific* color twice in a row is $\frac{1}{36}$. For example, the probability of getting red twice in a row is $\frac{1}{36}$. Likewise, the probability of getting white twice in a row is $\frac{1}{36}$.

However, the probability of getting the same (but further unspecified) color twice in a row is $\frac{1}{6}$. So, for example, the probability of getting red or white or green, or ... twice in a row is $\frac{1}{6}$.

So yes, your thoughts are good on this. What's important, as always, is just to get clear on exactly what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. In very general terms, what you have done is turning a statement "colour red on the first AND colour red on the second" into a product of terms. In general if two events are independent:
$$
\Bbb P (\text{event A AND event B}) = \Bbb P (\text{event A})  \Bbb P (\text{event B})
$$
Where $\Bbb P$ is the value of the probability of a certain event. For the two colours in a row case you had $(1/6)(1/6) = 1/36$. The second calculation has:
$$
\Bbb P (\text{whatever colour AND the same colour as before}) = \Bbb P (\text{whatever colour})  \Bbb P (\text{the same as before}) = \frac 6 6 \cdot \frac 1 6 = \frac 1 6
$$
Clearly $\Bbb P (\text{whatever colour})$ must be $1$ and once you have obtained the colour, $\Bbb P (\text{that colour})$ must be $1/6$.